# Need Proper JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to show data in Attribute and Value form but data is getting is in direct form.

I am trying this

**Getting Data in this FOrm**

```
{"FirstName":"sbncf","EmailAddress":"jscn@jnsc.cs","LastName":"jj","Phone":"653736","SearchBy":"jhjnjn"}
```

**But i need in this Form**

```
$data_string = '[{"Attribute":"FirstName","Value":"Bret"},{"Attribute":"LastName","Value":"Lee"},{"Attribute":"EmailAddress","Value":"bret.lee@australia.com"},{"Attribute":"Phone","Value":"8888888888"},{"Attribute":"SearchBy","Value":"Phone"}]';
```

I am using AJAx and using this

```
$data_string =  json_decode(json_encode($_POST));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVsXV.png)

Comment: you are added php tag in this question, so please give json generated php code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store data into an another array, new array must contains `Attribute` and `Value` indexes, something like this example:

```
// testing $_POST data
$post = array();
$post['FirstName'] = 'sbncf';
$post['EmailAddress'] = 'jscn@jnsc.cs';
$post['LastName'] = 'jj';

$newArray = array(); // initialize new array
$i = 0;
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$i]['Attribute'] = $key;
    $newArray[$i]['Value'] = $value;
    $i++;
}

//use json_encode here:
$data_string =  json_encode($newArray);
echo $data_string;
```

**Result:**

```
[{"Attribute":"FirstName","Value":"sbncf"},{"Attribute":"EmailAddress","Value":"jscn@jnsc.cs"},{"Attribute":"LastName","Value":"jj"}]
```

Comment: Hi,Please check the image above i am unable to fetch value from the form.

Comment: @AKSHATGOYAL: this is an another question, probally you forgot to add encrypt type in form, please create a new question and close this question by mark as accepted the answer from left hand side check mark. this will help to future visitors